# Use the same socket.io connection in multiple HTML pages in node js

Tags: node.js

-Follwing is the jquery code I have written in my (dashboard.html) file

```
<script>
 $(function(){

 $("#username").hide();
var socket= io.connect();

$(document).on("click", ".help", function () {

    alert( $(this).attr('id'));
    socket.emit('help',{helper:$username.val(),requester:$(this).attr('id')});
});
});
```

---On clicking help button socket will emit an event "help" as you can see in the code.

---Following is the app.js file on server

```
    io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.on('help',function(data){
    console.log('rohi is goood',data.helper);
    socket.emit('loadList' , {helper:data.helper,requester:data.requester});

});
});
```

---On "help" event socket is emitting an event "loadList" in app.js file.
   Now I want to use "loadList" event in some other html file like            "chat.html".
   The code I have written is as follows for chat.html.

```
  <script>

      $(function(){

     // var socket= io.connect();

   // var socket= io.connect('http://localhost:3000/', { 'force new //connection': true });



socket.on('loadList',function(data){
    alert('inside help',$('#usernam').val());
    console.log('tatai',$('#usernam').val());
    if($('#usernam').val()== data.helper){
        $('#chatList').append('<p>'+data.requester+'</p>'+'<button value="chat"></button>');
    }
   else if($('#usernam').val() == data.requester){
                    $('#chatList').append('<p>'+data.helper+'</p>'+'<button value="chat"></button>');

    }
    else {
        alert('fuck off');
    }

});
```

The above code is not working. Please tell me how can I use same socket connection in the chat.html file.(loadList event is not working).

Comment: You need to provide an example of your code or some sort of research or tries you have done. This is not a "write me a tutorial" website.

Comment: @Mike Please have a look at my code and suggest me the solution.

Comment: First, take care of your code, it's not indented and messy. Why you don't just put it in a .js file and include it in a script tag?

Comment: Mike this just an example of what I trying to achieve in my actual code.

Comment: @MikeBoutin this just an example of what I trying to achieve in my actual code.  If you have  solution to my problem then please suggest the solution.

Comment: You can just define the path to your connection: ```io.connect('http://localhost');``` And if it's just an exemple, you can make your code looks better, it will attract more people to help you. You can add more details to your problem too, it's not precise. But you should create one file to handle all socket notifications.

Answer (score -1):

As your question is not complete so i am assuming you want to know if socket.io connection can be used on different html pages . Yes you can access it on every html page of your application as long as you have one server on which socket.io is used .

Every time a new user comes a socket session is created for that particular user and that user can access any page of your application .

Comment: @ ajay I have just updated my question. Please look at the code and suggest me the solution.